# Ruby deduct from instance variable same values from other

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, instance-variables

I have two instance values: @a, and @b, there are hash-like....
(will explain on pseudo examples)
For example in @a i have:

```
*Field1 | Field2 | Field3*

CONTITECH | CT942K1 | 123
CONTITECH | CT722K1 | 123
ATE | AB2123 | 123
```

in @b i have:

```
CONTITECH | CT942K1 | 456
BREMBO | TE132 | 123
```

How to do that @c = @a - @b will contain only values which are not in @b?

For example @c = @a - @b will contain:

```
CONTITECH | CT722K1 | 123
ATE | AB2123 | 123
```

So only if 2 field are same, i must delete from @a same value from @b...

If don't clear by examples, write in comments.... What i need is just delete from @a all same by (field1 and field2) entries in @b...
How to do this?

if this will help: code:
this is @b (@articles):

```
@articles = Article.find(:all, :conditions => ["ART_ID in (?) ", @search.map(&:ARL_ART_ID)])
```

and @a (@non_original):

```
@non_original = []
    nr_condition = "*" + art_nr.to_s.gsub(/[^0-9A-Za-z]/, '').upcase + "*"
    if art_nr.length > 3
      art = search_not_oem(art_nr)
      @search = CrossList.find(:all, :conditions => ['MATCH (cross_value) AGAINST (? IN BOOLEAN MODE)', nr_condition])
      if @search.present?
        @prlist = PriceList.where("id IN (?)", @search.map(&:price_list_id))
        if  @prlist.present?
          @prlist.each do |p|
            #@all_supp = Supplier.all
            #if @all_supp.find{|item| item.SUP_BRAND.gsub(/[^0-9A-Za-z]/, '').include?(p.brand.gsub(/[^0-9A-Za-z]/, '').upcase)} && art.present?
            #  logger.warn("!!!!!! if")
            #else
              @non_original << p
            #end                  
          end
        end
      end
    end
@non_original
```

what i need is to @res = @non_original - @articles, sure they have different fields, but with same data...

Comment: Instead of pseudo code, why not give actual ruby code that sets up @a and @b and what the result from b?

Comment: @FrederickCheung what you will see there? all is in db? also code is huge, and will not display anyting....

Comment: `@non_original` seems to contain `PriceList` objects, while `@articles` constains `Article`s. How do you want the subtraction to work?

Comment: @Chowlett I know that, this is the question! To delete from one, other, with same values!

Comment: @Chowlett  just if articles field1 and field2 value are same as non_original ffield1 and ffield2 then from non_original delete this row from object...

Comment: Ok, we can work with that.

Comment: @Chowlett have some ideas?

Comment: Well it helped clarify that you're trying to subtract 2 arrays which isn't at all what I thought you were asking from the first reading. looks like Chowlett has worked something out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@res = @non_original.reject do |obj|
  @articles.any? {|art| art.field1 == obj.field1 && art.field2 == obj.field2 }
end
```

That should put into `@res` all objects from `@non_original`, except for those whose `field1` and `field2` match those of any element in `@articles`. The objects in `@res` will be the same type as `@non_original` - that is, `PriceList`.

Comment: yes, os good.... just i need also something to edit... but for first look is good